# Hibernate: Whether session.get() needs session.getTransaction().commit()?

Tags: hibernate, commit

The Code is:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    SessionFactory fact = conf.configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = fact.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    News2 news = (News2)session.load(News2.class, 8);
    System.out.println(news.getId());
    System.out.println(news.getTitle());
    //session.getTransaction().commit();
    fact.close();
```

Why it still can print out the information since I don't invoke the commit() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start a transaction you must commit it.

The above works for you because it's a normal behaviour - you *can* read values within a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

you are reading the entity from the database not making any changes to the entity so transaction commit is not necessary on reads